# Unwanted space in multicols equation

Tags: multicol

I want to get rid of the space in the last equation. But I don't know how.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{NC}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{NC}}
\item $\displaystyle \int_0^\pi \sin^2 x\;dx$
\item $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^2\theta\;d\theta$
\setcounter{NC}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\smallskip

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{NC}}
\item $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \cos^4 x\;dx; \quad \quad \rm{Note:\;}\tan' (x) = 1+\tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$
\setcounter{NC}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you place the third `\item` in a `multicols{2}` environment if you don't want a column break to occur?

Comment: @Mico: thanks a lot for formatting my code. But I still don't know how to format it

Comment: @Mico: I have a lot of integrals that I want to display in multicol environment, and keeping the horizontal numbering.

Comment: `\rm` is not defined by default in latex. some classes define it for compatibility with documents from the 1980's but it does not take an argument, so  `\rm{Note:\;}` applies to the rest of the expression, not to `Note:`

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks. I keep learning from all of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress automatic column balancing, which is what's causing the apparently unwanted column break in the second `multicols` environment, you need to use a `multicols*` environment, not a `multicols` environment.

Some addtional points:

- Writing `\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}` is an accident waiting to happen. Please write `\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}`.
- I would place `Note: $\tan'(x) = 1+\tan^2 x = 1/\cos^2 x$` on a line *after* the line generated by `\item $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos^4 x\;dx$`.
- The code shown below provides a method that automates incrementing the `NC` counter. I would also load the `enumitem` package and use its `\setlist` macro to instruct LaTeX to not indent the numbers generated by `\item`. Tnis may come in handy in two-column layouts.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}
\newcounter{NC}

% New:
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{left=0pt} % save some horizontal space

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\apptocmd' macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\apptocmd{\item}{\stepcounter{NC}\RaggedRight}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle \int_0^\pi \sin^2 x\,dx$
\item $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^2\theta\,d\theta$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\smallskip

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{NC}}
\item $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^4x\,dx$

Note: $\tan'(x) = 1+\tan^2x = 1/\cos^2x$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll study thoroughly your answer and take all of it in account if I digest it, because I'm still a beginner.

Comment: I would guess @Rafiq doesn't need `NC` at all, and can use `enumitem` option `resume` ro restart the enumerate where the last one finished.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - That would be my guess too, actually. Howver, I don't think the `resume` option works as expected if the `enumerate` items are encased (entombed?) in `multicols` environments.

Answer (score 1):

No `multicols`, it's not the right tool. I suggest an array instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{showframe}% just to show the page margins

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
$\begin{array}{
  >{\displaystyle}w{l}{0.5\columnwidth}
  >{\displaystyle}w{l}{0.5\columnwidth}
}
\text{1. } \int_0^\pi \sin^2 x\,dx &
\text{2. } \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^2\theta\,d\theta
\\[4ex]
\text{3. } \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \cos^4 x\,dx &
\hspace*{\fill}\text{Note: } \tan' (x) = 1+\tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}
\end{array}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]